# Updating to Automapper v5 has error with .NullSubstitute

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm updating our automapper libraries from version 3 to version 5.2.0 and I'm getting this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Int32'
```

on this line of code in the mapping setup for two complex objects.

```
cfg.CreateMap<objA, objB>()
.ForAllMembers(config => config.NullSubstitute(string.Empty));
```

I'm guessing this is happening because it can't set int to null, and it's being explicit about it now, and in v3 of automapper it just ignored it. Can someone confirm that? Do I have to explicitly map each member type in version 5?

For this mapping the object has ints, bools and strings. Is there a way to tell it to map the strings to String.Empty when they are null and ignore the other types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortinately this is the AM5 behavior for `NullSubstitute` and also `ForAllMembers` does not support filtering and does not provide any information about the member being mapped.

As a workaround I would suggest performing a manual "fix up" using the `ForAllPropertyMaps` method which allows filtering and provides the necessary information:

```
cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(
    pm => "".Equals(pm.NullSubstitute) && pm.DestinationPropertyType != typeof(string),
    (pm, m) => pm.NullSubstitute = null
);
```

Comment: Will that apply to all mapped objects?

Comment: Yes. What else could `All` in `ForAllPropertyMaps` mean :)

Comment: I misunderstood your answer. I thought you meant remove the .ForAllMembers code and add the ForAllPropertyMaps for one mapping. But you are saying leave the .ForAllMembers code and add this new method to control what type the NullSubstitute methods apply to for every mapping, not just a specific one. In any case, this got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for not being clear, but I thought you are seeking for safe upgrade path, so the above is simply fixing the invalid values previously set by `ForAllMembers` calls. If you want all `string` members of all types to substitute "" to `null`, then you could remove `ForAlllMembers` calls from the concrete maps and use single `cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(pm => p.NullSubstitute == null && pm.DestinationPropertyType == typeof(string), (pm, m) => pm.NullSubstitute = "");` to set them up all.

Comment: Had this same problem. Nothing, not even the above solution would stop the dreaded 'coercion operator' error. So, after a couple of hours of trying almost everything, I just removed the NullSubstitute configurations, and it worked perfectly without them. Maybe not a 'solution', but it might help someone.

Comment: My case was that I misunderstood how `NullSubstitute` worked. According to the documentation, "The substitute is assumed to be of the _source member type_, and will go through any mapping/conversion after _to the destination type_." I was supplying a substitution compatible with the destination member instead of the source member. There was no conversion operator defined to change the substitute type to the source type, so I got the "no coercion operator" exception. After changing the substitute type to the source type, the error vanished.